# Qt OpenGL point size

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, 3d, glpointsize

I am using QOpenGLFunctions with modern OpenGL. I want to draw some GL_POINTS on my window but the point size seems to be really small. Usually, you can change the size of points with

```
glPointSize(4);
```

However, this code snippet does not exist in the QOpenGLFunctions wrapper, so I am not sure how to change them.

Drawing GL_TRIANGLES works perfectly fine for me.

I want to draw points to display a point cloud of real-world objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`QOpenGLFunctions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglfunctions.html#details), there is really no `glPointSize()` available. Why?

> The QOpenGLFunctions class provides cross-platform access to the OpenGL ES 2.0 API.

Cross-checking it on [khronos.org](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPointSize.xhtml):

> ```
> +--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Function /   |                             OpenGL Version                            |
> | Feature Name | 2.0 | 2.1 | 3.0 | 3.1 | 3.2 | 3.3 | 4.0 | 4.1 | 4.2 | 4.3 | 4.4 | 4.5 |
> +--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
> | glPointSize  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |  v  |
> +--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
> ```

So, it is supported for OpenGL but not for OpenGL ES.

There are two possible options:

**Option 1: `gl_PointSize`**

In OpenGL ES, you may use the GLSL shader variable [`gl_PointSize`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_PointSize.xhtml) instead.

(I found this "accidentally" while searching for appropriate doc. links – haven't known this before nor ever used it.)

[derhass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327517/derhass) provided the additional hint that this might be used with OpenGL (non-ES) as well if enabled by [`glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml).

> `GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE`
>
> If enabled and a vertex or geometry shader is active, then the derived point size is taken from the (potentially clipped) shader builtin `gl_PointSize` and clamped to the implementation-dependent point size range.

**Option 2: Use an alternative `QOpenGLFunctions_???` class**

Instead of `QOpenGLFunctions`, you may explicitly use a non-portable alternative (assuming you don't need to support phones, embeddeds or something like this).

The best overview in Qt doc. I could find: [`QAbstractOpenGLFunctions`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractopenglfunctions.html).

Comment: Addition to option 1: If you want to use the `gl_PointSize` vertex shader output on desktop GL, you have to `glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)`, otherwise, that value is ignored and the currently set point size from `glPointSize` is used.

Comment: @derhass Thanks. I added this hint to my answer.

Comment: Well, I think your update is a bit confusing now. You explicitely talk about OpenGL ES first, which does not have that enable bit and behaves as if it is always enabled, so on ES, it is not required. On desktop GL otoh, you have to enable it.

Comment: @derhass fixed it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested derhass, first **enable the point size** with this line in your **C++ code** (not the shader):

```
glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
```

Then as suggested Scheff, in your **vertex** shader code, add the `gl_PointSize` builtin function.
So for example if you wanted a size of 12 for a point, use it like that.

```
// main from your vertex.glsl shader (not from your main.cpp!)
void main() {
    ...
    gl_PointSize = 12;
    ...
}
```